# JS (jquery) заменить ID на ЗНАЧЕНИЕ (из словаря)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код на сайте (в разделах цифры 201399 разные, **приставки и окончания к id могу добавить без спец символов**, **задать class для td не могу**)

```
<td>id:201399</td>
```

Файл на другом сайте name.text (есть возможность выходные данные в нужном виде отдать
или **сгенерировать сам script.js с уже встроенным словарем и его подключить на сайт**), на Python вытягиваю через API с другого сайта и записываю в файл.

```
ID    | оценка
201399|3.69343
873053|3.80098
753375|3.77029
830159|3.37478
```

На сайте подключен
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Как с помощью js заменить

```
<td>id:201399</td>
```

на советующую оценку из файла(словаря) 201399 | 3.69343

```
<td>3.69343</td>
```

или, если искомого ID нет
на текст

```
<td>Оценки нет</td>
```

Если такой строки вообще нет - соотв. ничего не нужно.
Пробовал готовые решения, конкретный текст получается менять, а подружить все вместе не выходит.

Код таблицы:

```
<div class="detail-parameters-wrapper">
<table class="detail-parameters second">
<tr>
<th>
<span class="row-header-label">
Param<span class="row-header-label-colon">:</span>
</span>
</th>
<td>text text text text text text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
<span class="row-header-label">
Param<span class="row-header-label-colon">:</span>
</span>
</th>
<td> text text text text text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
<span class="row-header-label">
Rate<span class="row-header-label-colon">:</span>
</span>
</th>
<td>id:201399</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const a = JSON.parse('{"201399":3.69343,"873053":3.80098,"753375":3.77029,"830159":3.37478}');

const tables = document.querySelectorAll('.detail-parameters.second'); // привязка к таблице
tables.forEach(table => {
  const td = table.querySelectorAll('td');
  td.forEach(element => {
    const id = element.innerText.match(/^id.*?(\d+)/)?.[1];
    if (id) {
      element.innerText = a[ id ] ? a[ id ] : 'Оценки нет';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="detail-parameters-wrapper">
<table class="detail-parameters second">
  <tr>
  <th>
  <span class="row-header-label">
  Param<span class="row-header-label-colon">:</span>
  </span>
  </th>
  <td>text text text text text text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>
  <span class="row-header-label">
  Param<span class="row-header-label-colon">:</span>
  </span>
  </th>
  <td> text text text text text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>
  <span class="row-header-label">
  Rate<span class="row-header-label-colon">:</span>
  </span>
  </th>
  <td>id:201399</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `[...td].forEach(element => {
  const id = element.innerText.match(/\d+/)?.[0];
  element.innerText = a[ id ] ? a[ id ] : 'Оценки нет';
})` - мне так больше нравится))) Или сразу `td = table.querySelectorAll('td'); td.forEach...`. Хороший ответ! Просто так получается, что если `'id :45453095'` или `'id: 345083450'`, то уже не обнаружится.

Comment: Благодарю за код, но вероятно моих знаний не хватает чтобы понять вложенность элементов, файл я генерирую и подкладываю на хост, подключаю.
Но не работает, в исходный код сайта доступа нет, внешний движок.
Код таблицы добавил в запрос, там нет id, пробовал 
const table = document.getElementsByClassName('detail-parameters second'); // привязка к таблице
const td = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

не работает, в консоли ошибка

(index):101 Uncaught TypeError: table.getElementsByTagName is not a function
    at (index):101

Comment: @SergeyKM, тогда `[...document.querySelector('.detail-parameters.second').querySelectorAll('td')].forEach...` . `getElementsByTagName` делает выборку по тэгу только, это устаревшие способы, пользуйтесь `querySelector` и `querySelectorAll`. Внутрь любые CSS-селекторы. У последнего есть встроенный метод `forEach()`. Поэтому можно сразу `document.querySelector('.detail-parameters.second').querySelectorAll('td').forEach()`.

Comment: изменил ответ с учетом уточнения вопроса и комментария @Leonid

Comment: @SanyaH, я свой плюс уже поставил))) И верно, я не заметил, что автор пытается взять все таблицы с таким классом, я думал от по тэгу тоже ищет, а задает классы. И по поводу регулярки я вообще не уверен, может и правильно было учитывать именно наличие `'id:'`

Comment: Благодарю, все работает. Для тех у кого схожие проблемы дополню, что сработало только при размещении скрипта внутри тела тега body, в head - не работало.

Comment: в header-е нужно оборачивать в `window.addEventListener('load', () => { ... })` (вместо троеточия код) или даже лучше `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { ... })`